# Updating database with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let me explain situation, person is searching through skills and when clicked displays list of handymans with that skill, when user clicks on one of them, full details are displayed. user then clicks assign job link and is taken to a page with jobs along with checkbox and when desired job is chosen, and submit button clicked, I want a database to update "job_id" value in "handymen" database. How could that be done?

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Assign Job')

@section('content')

@section('content')

<form action="{{url('assignjob')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
     @foreach ($jobs as $job)
        <div>
            <label>{{$job->name}}</label>
            <input type='checkbox' value='{{$job->id}}' name='jobs[]'/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Assign Job">
</form>

@endsection


function search()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();
    return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
}
function details($skillId)
{
$skill = Skill::find($skillId);
$handymen = $skill->handymen;
return view('layouts/details', ['skill' => $skill,'handymen' => $handymen]);
}
function assignJob($handymanId)
{
    $assignJob = Hadnyman::find($handymanId);
    $jobs = Job::all();
    return view('layouts/assignjob',['jobs' => $jobs]);
}   
function jobassign(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('assignjob');
}
function skilledHandyman($handymanId)
{
    $skilledHandyman = Handyman::find($handymanId);
    return view('layouts/skilledHandyman', ['skilledHandyman' => $skilledHandyman]);
}
```

If a specific code is needed, please let me know

Comment: read about eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: Yes, I have done that, tables are connected using eloquent but still confused a bit on how to make that work

Comment: Make what work? The updating process?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Eloquent Relationship.
Handymen has many Job

```
class Handymen extends Model {
  ...
  public function jobs() {
     return $this->hasMany(App\Job::class);
  }
}
```

In your controller

```
function assignJob(Request $request, $id)
{
    $handymen = Handyman::findOrFail($id);

    // $request->get('jobs') = [1, 6, 7, etc...]
    $handymen->saveMany($request->get('jobs'));
    return ...;
}
```